# Why does Solr delete documents after import

Tags: mysql, solr, solr4

I import data from MySql over an Dataimporthandler. This works very well and I get this message:

> Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 2,172 documents. Deleted 0
>   documents. (Duration: 01s) Requests: 1 (1/s), Fetched: 2,172
>   (2,172/s), Skipped: 0, Processed: 2,172 (2,172/s)

But when I look at my Overview it says:

> Num Docs: 1470 Max Doc: 2172 Deleted Docs: 702

So 702 documents got deleted for a reason I cannot really figure out. In my schema I don't use any unique field or something that could make some trouble for duplicates.

---

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="xxx"
    user="xxx"
    password="xxx"
  />
  <document>
   <entity name="product" query="CALL getSolrProducts();" transformer="RegexTransformer">
      <field column="uuid" name="uuid"/>
      <field column="id" name="id"/>
      <field column="productimage" name="productimage"/>
      <field column="producturl" name="producturl"/>
      <field column="productpricenew" name="productpricenew"/>
      <field column="productpriceold" name="productpriceold"/>
      <field column="brandid" name="productbrand"/>
      <field column="productbrandname" name="productbrandname"/>
      <field column="productbrandurl" name="productbrandurl"/>
      <field column="productbrandimage" name="productbrandimage"/>
      <field column="productbranddata" name="productbranddata"/>
      <field column="productshippingcoast" name="productshippingcoast"/>
      <field column="productlink" name="productlink"/>
      <field column="color" name="color" splitBy=","/>
      <field column="colordata" name="colordata" splitBy=","/>
      <field column="productdescription" name="productdescription"/>
      <field column="upc" name="upc" splitBy=","/>
      <field column="productname" name="productname"/>
      <field column="productshop" name="productshop"/>
      <field column="productshopname" name="productshopname"/>
      <field column="productshopimage" name="productshopimage"/>
      <field column="productimagethumb" name="productimagethumb"/>
      <field column="productshopdata" name="productshopdata"/>
    <field column="cat1id" name="cat1id"/>
    <field column="cat2id" name="cat2id"/>
    <field column="cat3id" name="cat3id"/>
    <field column="cat4id" name="cat4id"/>
    <field column="cat1data" name="cat1data"/>
    <field column="cat2data" name="cat2data"/>
    <field column="cat3data" name="cat3data"/>
    <field column="cat4data" name="cat4data"/>
      <field column="size" name="size" splitBy=","/>
      <field column="sizedata" name="sizedata" splitBy=","/>
      <field column="recommendations" name="recommendations" splitBy=","/>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Anyone a pointer?

Comment: Two things in my mind: (1) is the data import handler the one and only route that modifies data in your index? or is there something else that changes the indexed data? (2) Would you post parts of your dataconfig? You can define delete statements there.

Comment: Yes, the data import handler is the only route that modifies data on this core.

Comment: Thanks, that does not look suspicious. How did you call/start the data import? Did you use `clean=true`?

Comment: For now I'm doing it over the Webinterface solr offers, but clean is checked. I think it's pretty much the same then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you checked `clean`, DIH first issues a "delete all" update query and then starts posting new documents. Once indexing finishes, DIH issues a commit, which will only keep the new documents that got posted and delete all the old documents which existed before the indexing started. Your database must have gotten updated, so you got more docs now and the 702 deleted docs correspond to the documents that existed in your index before indexing started. (Checking `optimize` in DIH will purge the deleted documents, but optimize may be expensive for large indexes and the deleted docs do not show up in search results anyway, so may not be of much benefit.)

Comment: Yup, that was where I was heading with my questions. That's it :)

Comment: For the record, have a read [in the Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler): clean : (default 'true'). Tells whether to clean up the index before the indexing is started.

Comment: @cheffe Oops, sorry for stealing the answer and the points away from you

Comment: No worries, enough out there :)